# OS 10.14 stop console from scrolling

Tags: mojave, console

It seems that since the new update, console will not stop scrolling. I have turned off the "Now" button, but scrolling up and highlighting a line pops out of view as soon as a new message comes in (which is many every second).

It makes it pretty hard to track anything down when you can't read the messages.

Does anyone know how to turn scrolling off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have been a glitch in console. After clicking "reload", the messages stopped scrolling when not in "Now" mode and it is now working as expected.

Comment: Good tip. This kind of worked, it eventually started scrolling again.  The "Clear' button worked better (with the side effect of clearing the messages I'd have liked to read!)

Answer (score 2):

The clear button also worked nicely for me. As an added bonus, "Now" button is working as it should: stopping the scroll when toggled off, and jumping to the most current entry when toggled on.